# Database table design for Restaurant Ordering System

Tags: android, mysql, database-design

I need help to design DB/table for Restaurant Ordering System.

1) Captain will take order on Android device and after Placing an order from Customer, he (captain) will Print Order.

2) Captain can alter/add order based on Customer's demand

3) Finally based on customer's demand captain will finalised bill and Print the bill

Some Cases for Placing Order

1) Place Order and not cancelled and finalised bill

2) Place Order - say 4 Burgers , after finish, again customer Place order - say 3 Burgers, not cancelled, and finalised bill

3) Place Order - say 4 Burgers , after finish , again Place order - say 3 Burgers, and Customer asks to Cancel 1 Burger, then finalised bill

4) Place Order - say 4 Burgers, then, Cancel 2 Burger, then after sometime, Place Order 4 Burgers then finalised bill

5) Place Order - 4 Burgers, after sometime, Cancel 2 Burgers, after sometime, Place Order 4 Burgers, after sometime Cancel 2 and then finalised bill

i have already created , menu_card (i.e item), table_info
Billing Table :

```
id
table_no
bill_no
item_name
quantity
repeat_quantity
print_status (Printed/Not Printed)
ongoing (Yes/No(if no -then finished) )
date_time
```

Which field should i add in case 3,4,5 for Placing an order
I am confused what if Customer ask for "Cancel Order" , after finish current Order, he asks for same Item.

New EDIT :
I am showing the List of Ordered Items, where captain can touch to update the order,
I m thinking to add cancelled_items_quantity in table and for every new order i will make new entry to database to add those order,
E.g. Customer has ordered 4 Burgers, then it will add to the DB, now after finishing it off, if he asks for 3 burgers, again new entry will be made rather to modify existing 4 to 7, and even if he cancels the order, suppose 2 from 3 Burgers, then update will be made on same entry i.e. it will update cancelled_items_quantity to 2 from default 0
Pls Help

Comment: i don't get what you are asking. "I am confused what if Customer ask for "Cancel Order" , after finish current Order, he asks for same Item."

Comment: i mean which field should i add to table to get proper functionality to Add/Update or cancelling order

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want separate tables.

1) billing_info

2) table_info

3) item_info

Then correlate to each other as your requirements. Add a 'status' field or similar in item_info so you can easily update its value whenever user request changes.

**EDIT**

How about for item_info table, for each individual item that customer has ordered, create an entry. Then any changes, update the status.

I visualize on the android tablet, i can see a whole list of every items that customer has ordered.

Eg.

1 steak
1 ice tea
1 steak
1 coffee
1 coffee

So for each item there can be 2 options.
1) to remove the entry before confirmation
2) to change the status after confirmation

Before confirmation, changes are just on the UI only. So we can use option1 to update the UI. I supposed the complications come after confirmation and customer wants to change the order. So we use option2.

2 steak ordered. Now customer wants to cancel 1. So waiter just change the status of 1 steak to 'cancel'.

Comment: thanks, i already have created those table, my concern is to what to do for cases 3,4,5 in placing an order, which field should i add,

Comment: i m thinking i should add cancel_quantity , and for each new order new entry will be added to the DB even if Item is already served. E.g. Customer has ordered 4 Burgers, then it will add to the DB then after finish, if he asks for 3 burgers, again new entry will be made rather to modify existing 4 to 7, and even if he cancels the order, suppose 2 from 3 Burgers, then update will be made on same entry i.e. it will update cancel_order to 2 from default 0

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with making a separate table for items, orders and bills. Since one bill can contain multiple orders and an order multiple items.

As for your example cases, only write finalised data to the database. Keep non-finalised orders in memory on the app. Once the user clicks 'Ok' or 'Finish' the order is finalised and you can write it to the DB.

If you would change the order every time in the database, you'd do way too much transactions which isn't good.